# PRAW subreddit member filter

Tags: python, reddit, praw

is there a way to find Reddit subreddits who has 1k followers using praw library?
I've tried looking into praw's docs but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.